# Messed up javac

Tags: java

Im relatively new to Ubuntu and was playing around with a few notes I received from one of my lecturers. I had a file called "eg.java" which was just a small file with no relevant info that I was using to test Java. I then typed set > eg.java, and now Im receiving 100 errors whenever I try to compile anything. Again, Im new to Ubuntu so Im not really sure what I did, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The command you issued:

```
set > eg.java
```

Overwrite the `eg.java` file with other text (specifically, the output of the `set` command).

You'll need to grab this file again.

Comment: Can you explain that in simple terms? Im a bit of a newb when it comes to this. Tell me what it is that I did wrong, and what Im doing to fix it. Appreciate the help.